# UIPageViewController - load it with a PDF or Images

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, xcode4, uipageviewcontroller

i would like to know how can i populate/load the UIPageViewController ( the based project given in xcode 4.2 ) with a PDF file or Images. Could you help ? where should i add some code, what should i add to the project ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: yo man, that sounds good ! yerochewski@gmail.com, thanks ! 
happy new year :) 
if you can make the beginning of my year good you will be awesome ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add PDF you must add a UIWebView on your view and open pdf here

Update 1 -

Here is how you can load a local file in UIWebView.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Comment: Or use the core graphics methods to draw a PDF, it isn't that hard.

Comment: yes .. but opening pdf in UIWebView is much easier for beginners

Comment: Do i need internet for the webview ... ( oupsy :^o )

Comment: thanks a lot ! i'm going to try it as soon i'm done with what i'm doing right now, but it is what i was looking for !

Do you know how i can add a listview under it to scroll on all of my pdf pages quickly ( as the list view on the photo application of the ipad ).

Answer (score 2):

> i would like to know how can i populate/load the UIPageViewController ( the based project given in xcode 4.2 ) with a PDF file or Images

A "page" in a page view controller is a view controller (UIViewController). You create a UIViewController subclass and hand it to the page view controller, and the page view controller displays its the UIViewController's view. That's all there is to it! So you can display anything you want to. You can readily design your UIViewController subclass's view in the nib just as you would any other view controller.

Answer (score -1):

Read the documentation for UIPageViewController. You need to implement a few delegate methods to give it child ViewControllers that manage the content on each page. For pdf's your viewController would need to include a UIWebView.

Comment: Ok thanks man, it means that my application needs internet ? ... right ?

Comment: No, internet not required.  You can make a url from a file path (see documentation for NSURL) and give that to the UIWebView.  Its easy to use UIWebView because it has PDF handling already built in. Despite the name it does not have to be online.